# how to add font awesome using librarie

Tags: magento2, font-awesome, library

in my case, I have added this font awesome by declaring it in the header.

is there any way to inject this font awesome by libraries on the resource of my module and not call it externally by link

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. You need to download the fontawesome zip package and add the required css files under your theme.
   Steps to add the CSS files in your theme:

- Go to directory `app/design/frontend/YourVendor/YourTheme/web/css` .
- Unzip the downloaded fontawesome zip package under `fontawesome` directory.

2. To include/call a CSS file, add the `<css src="..." />` block in  section in a layout file. `app/design/frontend/YourVendor/YourTheme/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml`

> ```
> <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
>     <head>
>         <css src="css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
>         <css src="css/fontawsome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
>     </head>
> </page>
> ```

3. Deploy your static resources (Theme changes):

- `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
- `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f`
- `php bin/magento cache:flush`

Now check your css file will be added on your website.

Comment: thank you for your reply , i have added a zip folder contains lot of folder , i have on it css/all.css and css/fontawsome.css , i can't find fontawsome-all.css as you said , it didn't work for know

Comment: Yes you have to add your css file path in layout file. Please check my updated answer @magNif.

Comment: @magNif Please upvote and accept my answer as a solution if it looks helpful to you. Thank you :)